# Automatic margin doesn't center elements in div

Tags: html, css

Lately I was creating a searchbox for my website, but I wanted it to be constantly centered in every y and x dimension.

I have div container `searchbox`:

```css
.searchbox {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  top: 55px;
  height: 115px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Inside `searchbox` container, I made special `mover` container:

```css
.mover {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

As you see width is 50% because I thought it would center it, but it didn't, and margin is automatic, which I don't think even works without 50% width.

---

[Full code](https://jsfiddle.net/uda77168/1/) and [Result](https://jsfiddle.net/uda77168/1/embedded/result/).

I think my style is kinda messed up and there are useless things which may affect automatic margin.
What may the problem be? does `margin: auto;` doesn't work with current position of div? What do I need to change? If not, what's the problem?

I will be very thankful if you upload solution on my current fiddle.

Comment: This won't work if everything _inside_ your box is bigger than 50% of the width of the wrapper (aka, the centering seems to work correct;y, but on small sizes the content is aligned to the left of the centered box and overflows on the right). You `px` sizes are probably the culprit. The `margin: 0px auto` seems to be working fine.

Comment: Actually it does, but the `input.search` has width of `740px` (which goes out of the `50% width` box).

Comment: If you add a `max-width: 100%;` to the `input.search` that should fix it

Comment: And also add some widths to the blocks below (`max-width: 50%`) and the inputs in that one also need a max-width, etc....

Comment: Thank's for responses, can you edit my problem in jsfiddle? i couldn't understand what things do i need to change, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATED ANSWER

Here is correct code: https://jsfiddle.net/uda77168/7/

### First...

**1.** Removed all `absolute`, `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` CSS properties.
**Reason:** Absolute positioning is generally a bad thing to do, because it gives sites an unresponsive layout.
**2.** I've also removed `float` CSS properties.
**Reason:** `float` is not bad, but it's unnecessary if you're using flexbox.
**3.** Set `.search {width: 100%}`
**Reason:** make the search bar bigger.
**4.** Removed width properties for `#condition` and `#stattrack`.
**5.** Made the margins more consistent.
**6.** Placed `<label>` before `<select>`.

### Center Vertically

**1.** `<body>` is the flexbox that will center things vertically. In order for that to work, the `width` and `height` for `<html>` and `<body>` have to be defined.

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**2.** Next, we need to define `<body>` as a flexbox and give it some flexbox properties:

```
body {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

You can just copy-paste flexbox code like the one above from [here](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html).

### Center Horizontally

**1.** Create a div around `.statbox`, `.conbox`, and `.rarbox`, and give it a width and make it a flexbox (again, the flexbox code is copied):

```
<div class="horizontal-flexbox"></div>

.horizontal-flexbox {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**2.** I've also set `.statbox`, `.conbox`, and `.rarbox` each to be 33.3% width long. Added together, that's 99.9% – just under 100%.

```
.horizontal-flexbox > div {
   width: 33.3%;
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**3.** I've also included some other stuff, but that's not important. Make sure you learn flexbox, it's real useful!

Comment: Hello, Thank's for answer, i want to center it horizontally, i'm not very experienced in flexbox positioning, can you provide code solution? Thanks!

Comment: here you go, you owe me a beer

Comment: Thanks! I owe you more than a beer! I actually wanted horizontal centering only, for every menu, so i just added your code to `body {` and removed `align-items`, Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

Your `input.search` class has a specified width in `px` which is larger than the container.

```css
.search {
    width: 100%;/*changed this line*/
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

However using percentages can lead to unpredictable layouts when viewed on different screen resolutions.

Comment: Thank's very much, it almost solves my problem, but when i scale browser, it doesn't move, how can i make it so it constantly get's positioned in center (floats in center)? Thanks!

Comment: @ShellRox The Search box input does remain central. However your drop-downs are absolutely positioned so will not be placed exactly where you set them to. May i suggest you read up on css positioning. -> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp and the css box model

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.searchbox {
    display:flex;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    justify-content:center;
    -webkit-justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    -webkit-align-items:center;
}
```

And

```
.mover{width:50%;}
```

Comment: Hello, this would just mess up elements going too seperated.